# Sorting one array into another- C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

So I am trying to write this function where the input parameter array will be taken and copied into another array but in a sorted way. For example: an input parameter of `3, 1, 9, 8` will copy into the target array `1, 3, 8, 9`.

This is what I have so far but it only copies the smallest element in every time. I'm looking for a way to "blacklist" smallest values that are discovered in each pass.

```
void sort_another_array(int *param, int *target, int size){
    int i, j, lowest = param[0];
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if(param[j] < lowest){
                lowest = param[j]
            }
        }
        target[i] = lowest;
    }
}
```

Of course I could have another array of already found lowest values but that's more unnecessary looping and checking and adds to the already terrible n^2 complexity. Is there an easier way to do this?

I'm completely new to C, so please do restrict it to simple programming concepts of logic statements, using some flag variables etc..

Comment: Why don't you copy the array and then sort the new array in-place with the algorithm of your choice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms ?

Comment: I thought about it but then I kept going with my original idea and wanted to see if I could crack it open. It's like an itch now and I'd like to see a solution to this if only for my sanity's sake.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). As it turns out, selection sort is actually easier to implement in place as that article shows.

Comment: @kaylum I can't change the data of the array I'm passing in. I have done in place sorting before. Which is what made this so annoying to me when I realized I couldn't change the param array. I thought it would be relatively simple.

Comment: Copy the array into the target and then do in place sort of the target?

Comment: Seems to be the popular solution. Appreciate your input. I was just stumped by this and was just wondering if someone could devise a clever way to do it while maintaining the complexity.

Comment: @kaylum If i said in place wasn't an option at all, what would you suggest? In place, for reasons too detailed to explain won't work too well with what I'm trying to do. It's got my head scratching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probably most straight-forward way to do this is to first copy the whole array and then sort the new array in-place using a [standard sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).

However, if you want to keep the current structure, the following would be an alternative when all elements are unique:

```
void sort_another_array(int *param, int *target, int size) {
    int i, j, past_min = INT_MAX, current_min = INT_MAX;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (i == 0 || param[j] > past_min) {
                if (past_min == current_min || param[j] < current_min) {
                    current_min = param[j];
                }
            }
        }
        target[i] = current_min;
        past_min = current_min;
    }
}
```

What this does is keeping track of the previously lowest element found (`past_min`). The next element to find is lowest among all elements greater than `past_min`. I.e., we want both `param[j] > past_min` and `param[j] < current_min` to be true. However, the first element to add to `target` (i.e., when `i == 0`) will not have a lower element before it, so we add an exception for that. Similar, the first element satisfying `param[j] > past_min` in a pass will not have any element to compare with so we add another exception using `past_min == current_min` (this is true only for the first element found in a pass).

If you have duplicates in the array, this might work:

```
void sort_another_array(int *param, int *target, int size) {
    int j, past_min, current_min, write = 0, round_write = 0;
    while (round_write != size) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (round_write == 0 || param[j] > past_min) {
                if (write == round_write || param[j] < current_min) {
                    current_min = param[j];
                    write = round_write;
                    target[write] = current_min;
                    ++write;
                } else if (param[j] == current_min) {
                    target[write] = current_min;
                    ++write;
                }
            }
        }
        round_write = write;
        past_min = current_min;
    }
}
```

Basically it's the same idea, but it writes all elements of the minimum value in the same pass.

Comment: In your first code, if I write `past_min = INT_MIN;`, can I simply use `param[j] > past_min && param[j] < current_min` as the condition?

Comment: @sunqingyao It will not work without additional changes unfortunately. After the first pass, it sets `past_min = current_min`. Thus, for all subsequent elements `param[j] > past_min && param[j] < current_min` will always be false.

Comment: Note that the use of `INT_MAX` is a bit misleading in this case. It's not, as one first would expect, to make `param[j] < current_min` true in the first pass. In most cases, any initial value of `past_min` and `current_min` would work as long as they are the same. The one exception is when the smallest element in the whole array is that initial value, in which case it will be skipped for the second smallest. However, the only time `INT_MAX` is the smallest value is when it's the only value, so we are safe to initialize with that.

Comment: @FredrikSavje Would it be easier to store the sorted indices and not the physical elements of the array in the new array and use that as a map later on? For example, the param array of 3, 1, 9, 8 would result in the sorted array being filled with 1, 0, 3, 2 (which are the indices of the elements appearing in sorted order).

Comment: @samz_manu In a way it would be easier when there are duplicate elements. It is then straight-forward to make all elements unique by doing a two-level sort: first sort on value and when ties on index (the sorting would also be stable). I.e., one could use the structure of the first example even if there is duplicate elements. However, I wouldn't delve too deep into this; if you want to learn more about sorting, I suggest you read up on existing algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a modified insertion sort algorithm to solve this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort_another_array(int *param, int *target, int size)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i ++ )            // do for all elements in param
    {
        int j = i - 1;
        while ( j >= 0 && target[j] > param[i] ) // find index of element in target which is samler or equal than param[i]
        {
            target[j+1] = target[j];             // shift forward element of target which is greater than param[i]
            j --;
        }
        target[j+1] = param[i];                  // insert param[i] into target
    }
}

#define SIZE 10

int main( void )
{
    int a[SIZE] = { 9, 8, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6 };
    int b[SIZE];

    sort_another_array( a, b, SIZE );
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i ++ )
        printf( "%2d", b[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am providing, has a limitation that: If there are no duplicates in the array, then this will work:

```
void sort_another_array(int *param, int *target, int size)
{
 int i, j, lowest;

 for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
    int k = 0;
    if( i > 0) // for all except first iteration
    {
     while(param[k] <= target[i-1]) // find the one greater than the last one added
      k++;
    }
    lowest = param[k];

    for(j = 1; j < size; j++)
    {
        if( ( i==0 && param[j] < lowest ) || ( i > 0 && param[j] < lowest && param[j] > target[i-1])) // for all except first iteration the min found should be greater than the last one found
        {
          lowest = param[j];
        }
     }
     target[i] = lowest;
 }
}
```